# Liferay 6.2 Kaleo notification e-mail can't call operations of services

Tags: liferay, velocity

I'm developing a custom kaleo workflow with e-mail notifications. For notifications, I'm using Velocity and I would like to get some information from Liferay services. This is a small code sample that gives me problems:

```
#set ($resourceUtil = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleResourceLocalService"))
$resourceUtil
#set ($resourcePK = $getterUtil.getInteger($entryClassPK))
$resourcePK
#set ($resource = $resourceUtil.getJournalArticleResource($resourcePK))
$resource
```

If I use the previous code, the notification that I get is the following:

```
com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.impl.JournalArticleResourceLocalServiceImpl@3baa7cf0
6563724 
$resource
```

As you can see, I get the correct JournalArticleResourceLocalService, I get the correct value for the resource PK, but when I call the operation to get the resource, I always get a null.

This is a sample with a resource but I've tried with some other lifeary services and I always get no response. This leads me to think that perhaps I've to enable some property or do something different to be able to call the service operations?

Any hiny will be appreciated. I'm using Liferay 6.2. The same code in Liferay 6.0 works fine...

Comment: The right method signature is 
#set ($resource = $resourceUtil.getArticleResource($resourcePK))

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with

```
com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleResourceLocalServiceUtil
```

instead of

```
com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleResourceLocalService
```

still, this is just my first advice looking just on code. If this won't solve your problem I will try test it later on my environment.